# select option selecting only default value

Tags: php, html, select

Below is my html & php code. I don't know where am going wrong. But whatever option I select, it goes to the default. Like even if I select header3, it goes to header default. Can someone please help me. Thanks

HTML

```
<tr>
<td>Select Header</td>
<td>
  <select name='meta[choose_header]'>
    <option value='header_default' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header_default" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header Default</option>
    <option value='header1' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header1" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 1</option>
    <option value='header2' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header2" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 2</option>
    <option value='header3' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header3" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 3</option>
    <option value='header4' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header4" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 4</option>
    <option value='header5' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header5" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 5</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

PHP

```
  <?php if ($post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header1"){ ?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("address1")?></p>
    <?} elseif ($post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header2") { ?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("address2")?></p>
  <?} elseif ($post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header3") { ?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("address3")?></p>
    <?} elseif ($post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header4") { ?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("address4")?></p>
  <?} elseif ($post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header5") { ?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("contact_address5")?></p>
  <?} elseif ($post->get_meta("choose_header") == "default") { ?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("address_default")?></p>
  <?}
  else{?>
    <p><?=$theme->get_option("address_default")?></p>
  <?}?>
</div>
```

Comment: possibly your '$post->get_meta' method has problem

Comment: can you provide full codes that currently in HTML code ?

where is that <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header1" ? "selected" : "" ?>  coming from ?

Comment: It worked fine with two options(header1 & header2). I added default &  3 more options. Since then it started behaving weird.

Comment: first step is print out the `$post->get_meta("choose_header")` and make sure about this method works correctly.

Comment: try this code top of all html code and see what it displays, print_r($post->get_meta("choose_header"));  and tell me what it prints.

Comment: @user3531929 prints the default even you select other items ?

Comment: @Farshad Yes. It prints default and goes back to default option.

Comment: I think you must check the `$post->get_meta` method . It seems to not work properly. also @JonDinham said too

Comment: As I said, there is no problem with this method when I have only two options. As soon as I add default option, it is behaving strange.

Answer (score 0):

I changed code to below & it started working. I still don't know what went wrong. If anybody understands, please explain me. Thank you.

```
<tr>
<td>Select Header</td>
<td>
  <select name='meta[choose_header]'>
    <option value='header1' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header1" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 1</option>
    <option value='header2' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header2" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 2</option>
    <option value='header3' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header3" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 3</option>
    <option value='header4' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header4" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 4</option>
    <option value='header5' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header5" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header 5</option>
    <option value='header-default' <?=$post->get_meta("choose_header") == "header-default" ? "selected" : "" ?> >Header Default</option>
  </select>
</td>
```